# How to Add a connection string in web.config when Working with SQL server management studio?

Tags: c#, .net

ConnectionString Not Working
I am working with SQL server management studio.
I have created a simple Insertion with SQL server management studio.

```
ssms : windows authentication
and .net
DataConnections:writeclick database name->severname(DEVISSHAHID)->windows authentication.
```

**web.config**

```
  //<connectionStrings>
   // <add name="ConnStringName" connectionString="Data Source=DEVISSHAHID;Initial Catalog=InUpDelete;Integrated Security=True"/>
  //</connectionStrings>
```

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    string connstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

help?

I have Windows authentication?
both-ssms windows authentication
and
[windows authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7V2m.png)

Comment: I think that you need to provide User ID and password. Integrated Security wont suffice. Here [ConnectionStrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) you can find multiple examples of how to connect to database.

Comment: What do you mean by connection string is not working? what is the error?

Comment: Do a bit research before posting. this [link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/) might help you

Comment: @KinjalGor I m trying last 3 hour but data not inserted issue is connection string? I have windows authentication?no password and no username? see my image?

Comment: You are missing the server name and instance in the connection string.  Use Sql Server Management Studio and get instance from the login window.  Then add to connection string "Server=ServerName/Instance" (put in correct name/instance".  If SSMS says windows credential on the login then Integrated Security=True is correct and you do not need to have a user and password in the connection string.

Comment: @jdweng Data Source=DEVISSHAHID/instance; means which parameter passes in instance??help because I m trying both windows authentication and server authentication?help

Comment: If you can access the database in SSMS with windows credentials then use Integrated Security = true. DEVIDDHSHID is the server name and instance is which SQL server is being used.  A machine can multiple versions of SQL Server installed.  An Instance is like SQLExpress or SQLServer15,  The server is either the computer name or IP address.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for suggestion still I face this issue

Comment: @jdweng ```<add name="ConnStringName" connectionString="Data Source=DEVISSHAHID;Database=InUpDelete;Trusted_Connection=True;" />```

Comment: It is fixed?  if not Change Data Source to Server.  Still not working then you have to use SSMS and check if you can perform a query.  There is no reason that SSMS and c# should be different using windows credentials provided the instance is exactly the same in the SSMS login window and the c# connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in web config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStringName"
 connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Put this at the top of your code

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

and where you want to set up the connection variable

```
public partial class WebForm1: System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    string connstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringName"].ConnectionString;
}
```